# sql injection in createNativequery

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, sql-injection

```
String qstr = "select * from users where user_type=?1 offset ?2 limit ?3"
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(qstr, User.class);
query.setParameter(1, type);
query.setParameter(2, offset);
query.setParameter(3, limit);
```

Here type, offset and limit are user inputs.

Sonarcube is showing sql injection at createNativeQuery.
Can anyone say what is the solution to prevent sql injection?

Comment: Not sure, but it could be worth passing the literal string, perhaps Sonarqube is worried that you're building `qstr` dynamically.

Answer (score -2):

when assign your type is "1 and 1 = 1" cause sql injection

Comment: The point of using JDBC PreparedStatements and similar classes, like this one, is that when they substitute parameters they escape them to protect against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: No it won't as JPA/Hibernate will properly escape the values. Underneath it will use a `PreparedStatement` to do so.